# Android in-app billing: How to remove published item from product list?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play

I uploaded my application to test the in-app billing; specifically, a monthly subscription. I chose countries and prices kind of at random just for testing purposes, published the subscription (but not the app) and everything worked fine.

I deleted the apk and re-uploaded to start from scratch and fill out the details with all the proper values, but the subscription that I had published before with wrong values is still there! I don't see a delete option for this. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to re-name the package and then upload that re-named apk.